# Distinct clause is being ignored if a group clause is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

For the `LineItem` model, I am getting the sum of the order quantity for each line item.  In this example, I am only selecting a single line item for brevities sake.

The query:

```
LineItem
  .where(product_id: 14)
  .includes(:order, :product)
  .where(orders: { order_type: 1, order_date: (Date.today - 1.week)..Time.now})
  .sum(:order_quantity)
```

This generates

```
=> 88
```

which is inaccurate.  plucking the LineItem id's shows me that some line items are being queried more than once:

```
LineItem
  .where(product_id: 14)
  .includes(:order, :product)
  .where(orders: { order_type: 1, order_date: (Date.today - 1.week)..Time.now})
  .pluck(:id)
```

Lots of duplicates (still haven't figured out why this is happening in the first place):

```
=> [20330, 20330, 20358, 20358, 20361, 20361, 20363, 20363, 20369, 20405, 20405, 20452, 20452, 20513, 20513, 20513, 20527]
```

Ok, so lets call them distinctly...

```
LineItem
  .distinct
  .where(product_id: 14)
  .includes(:order, :product)
  .where(orders: { order_type: 1, order_date: (Date.today - 1.week)..Time.now})
  .sum(:order_quantity)
```

This generates

```
=> 27
```

which is accurate.  Since I'm also trying to pull multiple Line Items into a hash, I need to call a group clause at the end of the query; which is where the problem starts:

```
LineItem
  .distinct
  .where(product_id: 14)
  .includes(:order, :product)
  .where(orders: { order_type: 1, order_date: (Date.today - 1.week)..Time.now})
  .group('products.model_number')
  .sum(:order_quantity)
```

now even with `.distinct` being called, it has reverted to pulling duplicate Line Items:

```
=> {"LBP8652"=>88}
```

Am I missing something obvious here?  I tried tossing that `.distinct` elsewhere in the query, but
it still gives the same inaccurate results.

Comment: *"still haven't figured out why this is happening in the first place"* This is your actual problem and we do not have enough detail of your data or your relationships to help here. You could certainly construct more complex queries to circumvent this issue however that would be a lot of additional complexity to avoid addressing the root of the issue.

Comment: `.includes(:order, :product)` is very wrong. `.includes` is used to prevent n+1 query issues and the heuristics of what queries it createas are fairly complex. You want `.joins` or `.left_joins`.